# Question on Rotational mechanics

Tags: rotational-dynamics, friction, angular-velocity

> A plank with a uniform sphere placed on it, rests on a smooth horizontal plane. Plank is pulled to right by a constant force F. The sphere does not slip over the plank.

I always get stuck in such problems. I don't understand where will the frictional force act and what will be the direction of acceleration of the center of mass of the particle?

This is only a part of the question that I am solving. I just want to know the above-mentioned things. Once I get through this concept, I'll surely be able to solve my problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You concentrate on the sphere. It's only external interface is the point of contact to the plank. So obviously, that's where friction force is applied. If the plank moves to the right, it is trying to "take" the sphere with it. So the sphere "feels" the friction force to the right.

The friction is thus a force accelerating the sphere to the right and also a torque rotating the sphere anti-clockwise. Due to no slip, the linear and angular accelerations are related.

Does that help with the concept?

An alternative in some problems is to adopt the accelerating reference (e.g. the plank). If you know its acceleration, you can apply an opposite de-Lambert force.